# VBA search data based on list

Tags: excel, vba, list, search, criteria

I have a data table I want to search and return their values based on a list.   I'm able to find the list from G2 and return the value in K2 etc, however I need it to also loop on the list and get the next item on the list, in this case D030 and append the results under K4 and so on....please help?

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVlQu.png)

Here is the code:

```
Sub finddatalist()

Dim RCP As String
Dim finalrow As Integer

Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Data").Range("K2:N1000").ClearContents

RCP = Sheets("Data").Range("G2").Value

finalrow = Sheets("Data").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 1) = RCP Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Copy
        Range("K100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what Advanced Filter is designed to do (as well as other features like PowerQuery). Suggest you record yourself creating an advanced filter.

Answer (score 2):

```
finalrow = Sheets("Data").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
finalrowProject = Sheets("Data").Range("G10000").End(xlUp).Row

For n = 1 To finalrowProject
    For i = 2 To finalrow
        If Cells(i, 1) = Sheets("Data").Cells(n, 7) Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Copy
            Range("K100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
    Next i
Next n
```

Comment: I understand that you were reusing a method from the op's code but why wouldn't you improve `Range("A10000").end(xlup).row` to be `Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row` ?

Comment: Fantastic Lee!   Thanks for your help!  Works beautifully!  And Jeeped, thanks for cleaning up the code a bit too... Much appreciated gurus!